# Sugestão para atualizar aplicação WindowsForm

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, atualização, clickonce

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicação Windows Form em C#, esta é uma aplicação um pouco grande, gostaria de saber qual tecnologia uso para atualizar essa aplicação no computador do cliente. Tentei implementar o ClickOnce, mais vi que ele instala o sistema na pasta de usuários e não em arquivos de programas. Alguém conhece alguma plataforma que posso implementar em meu projeto? Minha ideia é de deixar os arquivos atualizados em algum ftp ou diretorio virtual(IIS) fazendo com que o aplicativo instalado na máquina do cliente verifica se tem atualizações neste "diretório Virtual ou FTP", se tiver ele baixa esses arquivos. Se algum souber de alguma forma sem ser o ClickOnce por favor me ajudem. Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o [WiX Toolset para gerar um instalador MSI para sua aplicação](http://wixtoolset.org/).

Depois disso, configure uma GPO no domínio Windows para instalar silenciosamente o aplicativo na máquina do usuário quando ele fizer login. [Veja como fazer isso aqui](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-gpo.html).

Comment: O Problema é que o sistema poderá ficar em muitas máquinas, é inviável ter que configurar a GPO para as máquinas. Você teria outra solução para isso?

Comment: Por que inviável? A GPO é executada sozinha pela controladora de domínio quando o usuário realiza o login dele.

Comment: Talvez eu não esteja intendendo muito bem este conceito. Vamos supor que eu gero um instalador MSI com uma versao de sistema 1.0.0.0(por exemplo), vamos supor também que este sistema esta instalado em mais de 500 máquinas. Quando eu fizer uma correção terei que mandar a versão 1.0.0.1 em um diretório virtual ou FTP, automaticamento o sistema instalado em mais de 500 máquinas terá que ver essas atualizações, baixa-las e substituir o sistema atual pelo novo. Configurando a GPO será possivel fazer isso?

Comment: Se há incremento de versão, a GPO atualiza o sistema nas 500 máquinas. Você só precisa configurar certinho o pacote pra suportar esse recurso de atualização.

Comment: Certo. Muito Obrigado. Irei implementar.